# simple C++ code linker error

Tags: c++, c++11, linker

Im trying to run a very simple snippet of code. I've been getting a linker error. My code looks like this:

main.cpp -->

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Complex.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   Complex c1(1.0, 5.0);  // this should create Complex object 1.0 + i5.0
   return 0;
}
```

Complex.h -->

```
#include <iostream>

class Complex {
private:
    double real;
    double imaginary;

public:
    Complex(double, double);
    void setReal(double);
    void setImaginary(double);

};
```

Complex.cpp -->

```
#include "Complex.h"
#include <cmath>

Complex::Complex(double x, double y) {
    setReal(x);
    setImaginary(y);
}
void Complex::setReal(double x) {
    real = x;
}
void Complex::setImaginary(double x) {
    imaginary = x;
}
```

The error I've been getting looks like this: [image: Error photo]

I have been trying to run my main for a while but I keep getting the linker error. I have no clue what's causing it. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You are not compiling or linking `Complex.cpp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
g++ main-3.cpp complex.cpp
```

mind the filename main-3, this is inconsistent in your question.
You have to feed all cpp files you are using into the g++ commandline to tell g++ where the code for the functions defined in the header lies. Read up on `.o` files, static linking and understand what that means.

Here is a little guide I follow to understand file inclusion and other factors:

c++ compilation is moronically simple:

1. read .cpp file
2. replace every #include statement with the text of the specified file (just dump it in)
3. If the resulting text still has #include directives (now from the header files), goto step 2.
4. Compile the hughe messy blob into a ´.o´ object file, replace calls to  functions with symbols and add to that file a table of known symbols and where they are defined.
5. if there are more .cpp files specified, start a new empty text blob. Goto step 1.
6. call the linker ´ld´ to link all object files together, replace symbols with the actual addresses.

Strictly speaking, above is a little bit of a lie nowadays and a lot is left out and no optimizations mentioned. But it is still a useful guide to the compiler's behaviour.

To use it to interpret your error: 
`Complex.h` got dumped into your blob, via the `#include` in `main.cpp` , but `Complex.cpp` did not. g++ generated an internal temporary .o file for you that contained something along the lines of

```
PUT 1.0 on Stack
PUT 5.0 on Stack
JUMP Complex::Complex
```

... and ran the linker ´ld´ with that .o file.
ld Could not find the address of the symbol Complex::Complex,
it needs a memory address to jump to.
If you compile Complex.cpp as well, the resulting Complex.o will have a symbol table with, for example, this entry:

```
Complex::Complex = 0xaaff
```

The linker, given Complex.o can now replace the symbol in main.o with an address.

```
PUT 1.0 on Stack
PUT 5.0 on Stack
JUMP 0xaaff
```